# Long delay to display passwords stored by Google

Tags: google-chrome

I am using my Google account to store/synchronize my login information. 
On my Chromebook, passwords are displayed almost immediately after the page is loaded, but on my Ubuntu desktop computer, the delay to see the stored passwords is about 10-15 seconds.

Is there something to do to shorten this delay?

a screenshot of the main page of chrome://sync-internals/ :
[image]

Comment: Are you for sure using Google Chrome on Ubuntu and not Chromium? Also what are the drive specs on the Chromebook and Ubuntu desktop? I have a feeling the delay comes from how the passwords are stored/retrieved. Has Ubuntu always had this problem, or is it a recent thing? Here is a [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=389139) about this issue. You're not the only one who has experienced this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using latest *version 51.0.2704.84* of Chrome on Ubuntu 14 or  16 and still having this issue, I think your Google Chrome profile is corrupt and you must create a [new Chrome profile.](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059?hl=en)

Before doing this you must [backup/export your bookmarks](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/96816?hl=en)

### How to create a new Chrome profile:

- Exit Google Chrome completely
- Open Terminal and navigate to `~/.config/google-chrome/`
- Rename/move the `Default` Folder to `Default.Bak` using `mv Default Default.Bak`
- Launch Chrome and Sign back in to Chrome

If you are on Ubuntu 12, this might be [related to Seahorse](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/-K1m6wp0G60). You can try [resetting Seahorse](https://askubuntu.com/a/65294/252822) or simply upgrading to Newer OS

### How to reset Seahorse:

- Open terminal and run the command below
- `rm ~/.local/share/keyrings/login.keyring`

Note: Doing this will delete all saved passwords from Seahorse

Comment: I have done that (removing Default dir of in chromium and chrome config dir), and it is still very long to see login info.

Comment: @Gael Which one do you have ? Ubuntu 14 or 16 ?

Comment: ubuntu  16.04 with gnome shell

Comment: @Gael Picked up my Ubuntu 16 again and have been playing with it since  you commented but it does't happen to me and I know this has been logged as a bug. I have tons of update pending in it too. Does `chrome://sync-internals/` show any problems for you ? How big is `.config\google-chrome\defaults\login data\` ?

Comment: in the sync-internals page, there is this error:` Passwords Error: ModelAssociationDone@../../components/sync_driver/model_association_manager.cc:406, datatype error was encountered: Association timed out.`

Comment: Login data's size is 18ko

Comment: @Gael Size seems to be fine but error in the sync page is not. I don't have sync error in any of my ubuntu 14 and 16 and haven't experienced any delays ever. Think of ways to fix it, also maybe put a screenshot of it in your OP. I will update if I find anything

Comment: @Gael Maybe try [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1181420?hl=en) for starter

Comment: I have added a screenshot.

Comment: @Gael Did  you tried the link above though ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41563/discussion-between-pun-and-gael).