# Chrome auto-fill saved passwords is very slow

Tags: google-chrome, performance, passwords, ubuntu-16.04

I have been a Firefox user for more than 10 years; all my passwords are saved by Firefox password manager and protected with a master password. Now I want to move to Google Chrome (**ubuntu 16.04**), so I removed the master password in Firefox, and imported all data from Firefox into Google Chrome. Everything is OK.

But now under Chrome, if I want to log into any page, I have to **wait 15 seconds** until Chrome autofills the credential fields. This happens on all sites which have saved passwords, even new passwords saved using Google Chrome!

What's wrong with Chrome? I have no such problem with Firefox on the same computer.

Comment: You could be a [affected by a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=389139#c35) if it doesn't work after creating new profile. Another user has reported similar issue but wierd I have none

Comment: Thakns :) They said Google Chrome for Linux uses gnome-keyring to store passwords, and gnome-keyring is very slow !! They really should develop their own password manager !!!

Comment: Nahhh they are planning to move passwords to db used by chrome if i read correctly.

Comment: Here is another [thread](http://superuser.com/a/1090182/270195) about the same

Comment: Do you have errors in this `chrome://sync-internals/` section ?

Comment: I have much the same problem with Chrome and Chromium on Ubuntu -- several versions over several years.  This seems to result from poor scaling behavior of the interface with gnome-keyring.  I have 800+ passwords and 1300+ bookmarks.  Very disappointing that this hasn't been fixed for so long!  It helps if you remove ~/.local/share/keyrings/*, log out, then back in and let the system regen its data from the Google server.  Eventually, it settles down, but the password retrieval time can be 10 seconds or more if you go to a new login web page.  Chrome on Windows,  FF on Ubuntu are fine.

Comment: I really can't use chrome with problem ! I'm using firefox now and won't plan to use Chrome anymore :(

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to drop the browser based password manager and go with a 3rd party password manager like Lastpass.

Some options

- [Lastpass](http://lastpass.com)
- [1Password](http://1password.com)
- KeePass
- Avast AV has one too

Personally, I have been using Lastpass for over 6 years, never had an issue, and it works beautifully on Android, Windows, Mac and Linux OS, and ok on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

This question is 6 years old and is probably not about this specific experience I just had but I updated from a Pixel 6 on Android 12 to a Pixel 7 pro on Android 12 and suddenly opening the password manager (pick a saved password prompt in the Gboard) was 3-10 seconds of wait time where before it was under 1.

In this case I thought resetting Chrome would help, but when I went to Chrome app's settings I did not see a reset option. It did show the password manager as a choice, which opened with the same slowness and spinner. It was then that I noticed that the application under which I am viewing passwords is "Google Play Services"; so I went to the app info, to "manage space" and then "Clear all data" then I also cleared the cache next to "manage space". After looking at the passwords again and waiting 5s for them to load, this brought the spinner time down under 2 seconds. Still not as fast as on the Pixel 6 but much faster than previously on the Pixel 7 pro.

I'm almost certain this has to do with restoring a Google One backup.

Answer (score 0):

This link [might help you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28019/how-to-make-chrome-chromium-remember-passwords-in-the-gnome-seahorse-keyring)

I strongly recommend you to use Google Chrome. I have tried to retrieve passwords from chrome and firefox. Firefox doesn't save passwords securely and anyone with slight knowledge can get them master passwords won't help. But with Chrome it is way harder so, Chrome is a more secure browser.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but with hindsight I'm not going to move to Chrome because if done it'll be very difficult to change to another browser : Chrome won't easly let me export my personal data like Firefox do !

Comment: that is the point

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. After weeks of agonizing over whether to reset my Chrome settings, I finally bit the bullet. Within 1 minute it was all fixed, my passwords were loading within a fraction of a second.

To reset your Chrome settings, click on the three dots (ellipsis) in the top right of the browser and select "Settings". At the bottom of the page select "Advanced" then at the bottom of the (expanded) page under "
Reset and clean up", select "Restore settings to their original defaults". Click the blue "Reset settings" button. All fixed in under a minute.

Comment: Didn't work for me.